# Default value on function by function call

Tags: php, function

Why cant I call a function for getting default value on runtime?

example:

```
public function booking($start_date=date('Y-m-d'))
{
...
}
```

error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in .....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible...

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function call. [PHPManual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

what you can do instead:

```
public function booking( $start_date=null ) {
    $start_date = is_null( $start_date ) ? date('Y-m-d') : $start_date;
}
```